# How to sort result set by the recent inserted record

Tags: sql, join, informix

How to sort my result set by the last inserted record ASC.

```
SELECT  a.* ,NVL(b.name ,'General') AS emp_name ,c.holiday_name 
FROM vacations a LEFT OUTER JOIN employee b  
ON a.emp_num = b.emp_num  INNER JOIN holiday c  
ON a.holiday_code = c.holiday_code  WHERE  a.auto_flag = 0  --ORDER BY a ASC
```

---

How to order this result ASC by the latest record inserted in `vacations`

Comment: Which column in the `vacations` table determines how old that record is?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen No column is like this :( so i want some way to sort this result by the last inserted record in `vacations`

Comment: Then you need to give us logic on how we can figure this out.  And keep in mind we know less about your schema than you do.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen if I didn't use `order by` the result set is ordered from the oldest inserted records to most recent. just i want the opposite!

Comment: Again, _which_ column are you using to decide how old a record is?  I can only ask you this so many times without losing patience here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen no columns, the user wants the most inserted record is displayed at the top when he clicks the submit button and all fields aren't related to that, may be the user grant somebody a vacation for old date recently, and he wants this record to appear at the top.

Comment: SQL tables for the most part have no internal order.  Rather, you impose an ordering on records when you query, but that requires using `ORDER BY` along with one or more columns.  If you can't specify the columns or logic, then your question cannot be answered.

Comment: What is the outline schema of each table that is referenced (`vacations`, `employee`, `holiday`) — the key column names and types?  Why do you have anonymous employees?  Why do you promote them to `General` when they exist?  Why do you put spaces before commas instead of after them?  Are any of the columns SERIAL or BIGSERIAL?  Why don't you record the date/time when the rows are inserted if you want to process them in the order in which they are inserted (or in the reverse of the order in which they're inserted)?  We'd like to help, but we can't help you if you don't help us to help you.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler :You are genius, but a lot of anger in your words :( 
I think it's more important in `SOF` to explain the technical problems not the business issues related to the problem.
but in general `vacations` HR uses to grant a vacation balance to a specific employee or all employees(general).and there's no serials in these tables. and  I don't add date/time when the rows are inserted because I thought it doesn't matter with the business but now the user want to sort the data according to the insertion date! I thought, there's some internal way to sort the data set .

Answer (score 2):

You should add InsertDate as a column in Vacations table, select in a subquery or CTE the row with the MAX InsertDate and order by its properties. Any other solution would be a hack, and unreliable, because, as Tim said, tables do not keep track of ordering.